# Saving from python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am new to Django.  I ran into a problem on chapter 5 of the Django book.  Basically I was trying to save `p1.save()` in the interactive shell and could not figure it out.

Specifically, how do I change from ... to >>> so I can save the the following input:

```
>>> from books.models import Publisher

>>> p1 = Publisher(name='Apress', address='2855 Telegraph Avenue',

...     city='Berkeley', state_province='CA', country='U.S.A.',

...     website='http://www.apress.com/')

>>> p1.save()
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S.

If you could tell me the proper name of ... and >>> (command prompt?) it would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you've entered something in the interactive shell and you see `...` it means what you've entered is incomplete in some way. Check for unclosed parens, brackets, etc. and/or indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...` is just an indicator that it is a continuation line. So, probably your statement is not complete yet. Press enter once again if you think the statement is over. Else check for unclosed parentheses, apostrophes, brackets or pay attention to indentation.

Comment: Thanks Cesar and Faruk!  I was able to get it to work now.  So weird.  I must have typed something wrong but now it went to the command prompt so I could save just like you both mentioned.  Thanks again!